# Does ALU read and write floating point number?

Tags: c

I know that for floating point operation FPU (Floating point Unit) is required and the ALU can only perform arithmetic operations. So I am using fixed point arithmetic.

These are the flollowing steps I am doing:

```
read floating point number.
Convert it into fixed point
Do all operation using fixed point arithmetic
Convert result into floating point
write o/p
```

My question is if there is no FPU present in system, how would it read floating point as input and output.

Does ALU read and write floating point number? If yes, how?

Comment: If you have no hardware FPU, then its behaviour has to be emulated in software.

Comment: Why did you tag this C if you are asking about low level hardware details? It doesn't seem to be related to a high level language like C at all.

Comment: What processor are you using? Fixed point processors typically come along with a SW library that supports floating-point operations. The compiler translates every floating-point operation into a library-function call.

Comment: A FPU can *also* perform arithmetic operations. I think the question need to be rephrased.

Answer (score 1):

No, the ALU can not read nor write floating point numbers as floating point numbers, just the FPU. From the ALU point of view an FP number is a series of random bits.

The FPU is present today for performance reasons; you have a dedicated piece of silicon on your CPU to perform FP operations.

Since floating point numbers are base two numbers with a mantissa and an exponent, you can always perform floating point operations using the ALU. Which, again, is slower than using a hardware FPU but gets the job done anyway.

For example you have [FLIP](http://flip.gforge.inria.fr/) which is a floating point library implemented in C to perform floating point operatins using just integer numbers; that's it, the ALU.

> FLIP is a C library that provides a software support for binary32
>   floating-point arithmetic on integer processors. This library is
>   particularly targeted to VLIW or DSP processors (that is, embedded
>   systems), and has been validated on VLIW integer processors like those
>   of the ST200 family from STMicroelectronics.
>
> This library provides software implementation for the five basic
>   arithmetic operations (addition, subtraction, multiplication,
>   division, and square root) with subnormal numbers support, and for the
>   four rounding-direction attributes (RoundTiesToEven,
>   RoundTowardPositive, RoundTowardNegative, RoundTowardZero) required by
>   the IEEE 754-2008 standard.

The GCC compiler also contains a [software emulation layer for floating point operations](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Soft-float-library-routines.html):

> The software floating point library is used on machines which do not
>   have hardware support for floating point. It is also used whenever
>   -msoft-float is used to disable generation of floating point instructions. (Not all targets support this switch.)

Answer (score 0):

With an ALU you can only use integer or use [fixed point arithmetics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_arithmetic). Otherwise, you have to emulate it. The emulation can be done either at compiler level (see [soft float](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Soft-float-library-routines.html)) or application level.